# Use of unresolved identifier when parsing json

Tags: json, swift, parsing

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print ("Error!")
        } else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as! [String:Any]
                    if let rates = myJson["bpi"] as? [String:Any] {
                        if let currency = rates["USD"] as? [String:Any] {
                            if let btc = currency["rate"] as? String {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                                    self.bitcoinlabel.text = "$" + btc

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    let btcprice: Double = btc
```

The issue is at the last line (Use of unresolved identifier 'btc'). How do I export the value I get from my data for use outside of the block of code or in other functions.

Comment: `btc` is only available inside the `if let btc = ` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`btc` is not accessible in the outer scope. You should do whatever you want to do with it in the scope only where it is defined.

Like this:

```
if let btc = currency["rate"] as? String {
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.bitcoinlabel.text = "$" + btc
        let btcprice: Double = btc
        // Do Stuff here with btcprice
        // OR Call another func from here like someFunctionWhichUsesTheBtcprice()
        // OR Add CompletionHandler in the Method definition like : completion: @escaping (()->()) and pass the function you want to call after you get the response with the method and call that function here like: completion()
    }
}
```

Also if you declare `btcprice` as a class variable like `var btcprice: Double?` then you should assign `self.btcprice = btc` in that block only. But whatever stuff you want to do with it should be done only after API returns the response otherwise the `btcprice` will be `nil`.

**Updated Code:**

You can use something like this:

```
func callAPI(completion: @escaping (Double) -> ()) {
    // Call Your API Here...
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print ("Error!")
        } else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as! [String:Any]
                    if let rates = myJson["bpi"] as? [String:Any] {
                        if let currency = rates["USD"] as? [String:Any] {
                            if let btc = currency["rate"] as? String {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                                    self.bitcoinlabel.text = "$" + btc
                                    if let btcDoubleValue = Double(btc) {
                                        // This will be called when we will get the response and btc value
                                        completion(btcDoubleValue)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

call this like this:

```
self.callAPI() { (btcprice) in
   // Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, what could I do to wait for the API response before declaring btcprice

Comment: @AleksanderFicek add a completion handler to your method signature

Comment: @AleksanderFicek call whatever function you want to call or do stuff you want to do after getting the `btcprice` where I have shown in the updated answer

Comment: @AleksanderFicek Chekout the updated answer now. I have added more explanation and some code to give you some idea on how to implement such use case of yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it as instance variable , but keep in mind call to API is asynchronous , so it's value will not be real until response returns , declare btc in class scope

```
 var btc: Double?
```

then

```
                if let btc = currency["rate"] as? String {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                                self.bitcoinlabel.text = "$" + btc
                                self.btc = btc 
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: How would I wait for a response I keep getting an error